# HTML one time clickable button

Tags: html, css

I have a button that should only be clickable once.  As of right now I am handling this in Javascript but there are three things I don't like about this:

- It doesn't work scriptlessly (note the button-effect does, long story short we're using Derby)
- It is stateful which causes other design troubles
- It seems like there should be a pure HTML or CSS solution for this as it's a pretty simple and presumably common feature.

JS-less way to do it?

Comment: Nope, that's what JS is for.

Comment: What does the button do?

Comment: How could this _not_ be stateful? Something has to remember whether the button has been clicked already.

Comment: Sorry, I don't believe there is a script-less solution.

Comment: Yes; this is not possible without JS

Comment: You could make the button a submit button. The form handler will just spit out the same page, with all the inputs the same, except that this button is gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this CSS trick:

```
<label><input type="radio" /><button>Your button</button></label>
```

CSS:

```
label>input[type="radio"], label>input[type="radio"]:checked~button {display:none}
```

This will cause the button to disappear when you click it once. For anything more "pretty", you will need to use JavaScript.

Comment: That's right, yet so so wrong (metaphorically). Many +1 for you.

Comment: +1 I was thinking along these lines, a radiobutton in it's own group. Once it's clicked you can't click it again

Answer (score 0):

JS-less way .. no.. Possible solution would be adding a JS function that adds`disabled="disabled"` and bind it to the button `onClick` and it will not be clickable any more.

Answer (score 0):

If the page is re-served (ie there's some server-side component), the server would have to send back updated HTML with a disabled button. Otherwise, you're changing the HTML on the client side, and Javascript is the way.